# Loading a SO Library, What can Linux do for me?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I write a loader for ELF64 programs. I now have the problem that I want to export and link existing so libraries in memory.

There are additional problems related to this. First of all here is what I know.

The so library is simply Position Independent Code that is compiled in a way that it can be just placed everywhere and run. It exports several symbols and I have a real problem to understand anything from here on.

Since starting an executable in Linux will issue a loading sequence about to load any required shared library and linking the external symbols right before the application starts.

So here are the questions:

1. Is it true that a so library is only loaded once despite how many programs request that library.
2. Is there a mechanism (linux function) I can call to load a so library on runtime other than by the loader.
3. Is it possible to optain the symbols (addresses) to invoke methods and relocate and bind system calls of an already loaded library. What is the API to use.
   4.Can I privately load a so library? Would it result into conflicts? Is there a scenario where this is actually done?

Comment: Ask not what linux can do for you, ask what you can do for linux!

Comment: I can deinstall it if it gets to demanding... .

Answer (score 2):

> Is it true that a so library is only loaded once despite how many
>   programs request that library.

The `.text` section only needs to load once, as it is shared among processes. The `.data` and `.bss` part is private to each process so it must be reloaded from the SO for each process that is dynamically linked to the SO.

> Is there a mechanism (linux function) I can call to load a so library
>   on runtime other than by the loader.

The `dlopen()` function and related. http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen

> Is it possible to optain the symbols (addresses) to invoke methods and
>   relocate and bind system calls of an already loaded library. What is
>   the API to use. 4.Can I privately load a so library? Would it result
>   into conflicts? Is there a scenario where this is actually done?

I'm not sure of what you mean by "system calls", as these are referred to the operating system, which is not a shared object (well, it is actually shared, but not in that way). To get symbol addresses and invoke functions within a loaded shared object, you can use the API exposed by the dynamic linking loader, which `dlopen()` belongs to.

Comment: For thoroughness, I'll point out that the `.text` section is only loaded once if it is position-independent code.  The fact that 64-bit address models may require position independent code in 64-bit shared objects doesn't mean a 32-bit library has to be position-independent.  I've run into non-PIC libraries where that fact caused some swap-space problems on machines that ran a LOT of processes but were configured with almost no swap space because in theory there was no need.  Until the multiple non-PIC shared objects used it all up.

Comment: Thanks for the infos. If i load a library which is already loaded, is it also loaded or do i get a handle to it? Is the library loaded for child processes also?

Comment: Also can I query all shared libraries that are already loaded by my process. What about multi threaded? Is process regarding to a single thread or a linux process as a whole? Meaning are shared libraries by definition thread safe?